# How can element field is retrieved form object array?

Tags: java

`Object obj[]={1,2,3,"HelloWorld!",node};`

Here node is a node class object having fields key and next..How can we get node.key here using object array index ..?

Comment: Is the node not always in the fifth position of the array?

Comment: Is your question "How do I access array elements in Java?" Because I have a feeling that might be a duplicate.

Comment: No the question is not about accessing the element from Array , it is about accessing the fields of the element . I'm new to java so I am really not sure that this question is valid or not. If I am writting like obj[4] it is returning the address like  Node@2a139a55 but I want the value which I stored in the field of key in this node.

Answer (score 1):

If the node is always at the fifth place you do :

```
Object obj[] = {1, 2, 3, "HelloWorld!", node};
Node n = (Node) obj[4];
// then n.key or whatever you want
```

---

If the node is not always at the same place you can do like this :

```
Object obj[] = {1, 2, 3, "HelloWorld!", node};
Node n = null;
for (Object o : obj){
    if (o instanceof Node) {
        n = (Node) o;
        break;
    }
}
// then n.key or whatever you want
```

Of course `Node` by the class name of the object `node`

Comment: Thanks a lot.It really helps me to understand the concept.:)

Comment: @DamineeSao you might think about "accept an answer" ;)